# JSON string validation in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to write a test in Python to validate that the payload I am returning is a valid JSON.

```
import json
s = '{"position": NaN, "score": 0.3}'
json.loads(s)
```

the code above doesn't throw an exception, while the string is obviously not a valid JSON according to my backend friend and jsonlint.com/.

What should I do?

Comment: why do you think it cannot valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parse_constant`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), documentation says:

> if specified, will be called with one of the
> following strings: -Infinity, Infinity, NaN.
> This can be used to raise an exception if invalid JSON numbers
> are encountered.

For example:

```
import json

s = '{"position": NaN, "score": 0.3}'


def validate(val):
    if val == 'NaN':
        raise ValueError('Nan is not allowed')
    return val


print(json.loads(s, parse_constant=validate))
```

Answer (score 3):

By default `json.loads` accepts `'-Infinity', 'Infinity', 'NaN'` as values. But you can control this by using [`parse_constant` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Quoting from the documentation,

> if it specified, will be called with one of the following strings:
> '`-Infinity`', '`Infinity`', '`NaN`'. **This can be used to raise an exception**
> if invalid JSON numbers are encountered

Answer (score 0):

According to `json.JSONDecoder` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) - "It also understands NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity as their corresponding float values, **which is outside the JSON spec.** [...] `parse_constant`, if specified, will be called with one of the following strings: '-Infinity', 'Infinity', **'NaN'**. This can be used to raise an exception if invalid JSON numbers are encountered."

```
import json

def exc(x):
    raise ValueError(f"{x} is not a valid JSON object")

s = '{"position": Infinity, "score": 0.3}'

d = json.loads(s, parse_constant=exc)
print(d)
```